# Backstage (from spotify) to rename solution when creating from template

Tags: c#, backstage

I'm using Backstage developer portal to allow developers create new projects easily from C#  .Net template.
I've got a template named *dotnet-api-template*, which has a sample API, sample unit tests and the like configured ready. The template has a solution file (.sln), a project file (.csproj) and a few code files.

When user creates a new project from this template, the solution name, project name and namespaces in code files remain the same (dotnet-api-template). User can change these but it requires a few extra manual steps I would like them to get rid of.

Is there a way to rename the 2 files (.sln and .csproj) to whatever the new project name is when backstage creates a new project from template? Must be somehow in the template.yaml file but I have not managed to figure out how.

Also I would like to change the code files to have different namespace (not dotnet_api_template). That means changing some parts of the code files contents.

All help is appreciated.

**Edit:**
I found out a way to rename the files. You can use the fs:rename step like this:

```
- id: rename
  name: Rename solution and project files
  action: fs:rename
  input:
    files:
      - from: ./skeleton/dotnet-api-template.csproj 
        to: ./skeleton/{{ parameters.component_id }}.csproj
      - from: ./skeleton/dotnet-api-template.sln
        to: ./skeleton/{{ parameters.component_id }}.sln
```

Still looking into how to change contents of some files

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the answer. You need to rename the namespaces in the template to ${{ values.component_id |lower|replace('-','_') }} and you can use ${{ values.component_id }} for the .csproj and .sln files.

So your template would have following files:

```
${{ values.component_id }}.sln 
${{ values.component_id }}.csproj
```

And the code would look something like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ${{ values.component_id|lower|replace('-','_') }}.Models;

namespace ${{ values.component_id|lower|replace('-','_') }}.Services
{
    internal class WeatherService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<WeatherService> logger;
        private readonly string[] weatherSummaries;

        public WeatherService(ILogger<WeatherService> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            weatherSummaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        }

        public async Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetWeatherForecastAsync()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = weatherSummaries[Random.Shared.Next(weatherSummaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you cannot run this code so make sure to first create your template to a degree you want and only after that make the changes above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful plugin for Spotify Backstage called `@plusultra/plugin-scaffolder-dotnet-backend`. You can run `dotnet new` to install a template and then create a project with it.

Just create `.template.config/template.json` in the root of your project folder.

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "Me",
  "classifications": [ "Backstage" ],
  "identity": "Backstage.Project",
  "name": "Backstage Project",
  "shortName": "backstageproject",
  "sourceName": "Backstage Project",
  "preferNameDirectory": true,
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "project"
  },
  "sources": [
    {
      "modifiers": [
        {
          "exclude": [ ".vs/**", ".git/**" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I recommend reading [dotnet new install](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-install) from Microsoft docs.

Comment: Did you run this with success? I've tried using this plugin but i'm having this error:

`Error: spawn dotnet ENOENT`